# How to replicate menu hover animations

Tags: html, css

I'm recreating the navigation from this [website](http://webflow.com) but can't get the animations quite the same. It's all working but seems to be a little off.

so far I've tried to increase and decrease the transition timing but it didn't get it anywhere near the example.

```js
const styleParent = (event) => {
  let ancestor = document.querySelector('div.nav');
  ancestor.classList[event.type === 'mouseenter' ? 'add' : 'remove']('servicesIsHovered');
};

let child = document.querySelector('li.three');

child.addEventListener('mouseenter', styleParent);
child.addEventListener('mouseleave', styleParent);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: acumin-pro, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  letter-spacing: .25px;
  margin: 0;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.main {
  width: 100%;
}

.section {
  width: 100%;
  background: #ededed;
}

.header {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav {
  width: 1100px;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 40;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
}

.nav li {
  color: #000;
}

.nav li a {
  cursor: pointer
}

.nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  width: fit-content;
}

.nav ul:hover li {
  color: #6C6C6C;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.nav ul li:hover {
  color: #000;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.nav li:last-child {
  margin: 0;
}

.nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 35px 20px 0;
}

li:hover>.sub-menu {
  height: 200px;
}

.sub-menu {
  height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  background: #2E2E2E;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  transition: height 0.5s ease;
}

.col-1-4 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 25%;
  position: relative;
}

.service {
  padding: 20%;
}

.nav.servicesIsHovered {
  background-color: #272727;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="nav">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a class="one">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="two">About</a>
      </li>
      <li class="three">
        <a class="">Services</a>
        <div class="sub-menu">
          <div class="col-1-4"></div>
          <div class="col-1-4"></div>
          <div class="col-1-4"></div>
          <div class="col-1-4"></div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="four">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

The animation doesn't seem to be as smooth as from the website. Also, they don't seem to be as in sync.

Comment: which website are you talking about ?

Comment: updated the post

Comment: Youa re talking just about the navigation, right?

Comment: They use some sort of technology I have never tried. However, I checked the source code, there is nothing special. The onmousenter events are JS controlled, it does not even look animated at all to me, just weird and jumpy, the JS was too obfuscated to read in the dev tools.
Just use very short animation times like no more thna .1s . Do not try to copy them, do it better>-)